# Executing my directive before another in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive A that I can't change (a predefined one).
I want to create another directive B where the link function should be called first (before A).
How can I do it? (let's say I don't know what is the priority of directive A - if it's relevant at all...).

The structure of the html is that directive B is a child of directive A:

```
<DirectiveA><DirectiveB></DirectiveB></DirectiveA>
```

Comment: This article is quite useful http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

- The priority is not relevant, it only matters when you have more than one directive on the **same element**.
- You don't need to do anything special as it is already the case. Child elements post linking functions always run before their parent's post linking function.
- If `DirectiveA` ( the parent element ) is deferring the creation of `DirectiveB` then you cannot do anything from inside `DirectiveB` to prevent it.
- **`ngRepeat`** / **`ngIf`** / **`ngSwitch`** / **`ngView`** / **`ngInclude`** are all good examples of directives which defer the creation of their child elements.

---

## Sources

From [$compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

> #### priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined **on a single DOM element**, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied.

From [Understanding-Directives article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Directives):

> #### Pre vs Post Linking Functions
>
> The difference is that `PreLinkingFunction()` will fire on the parent first, then child, and so on. A `PostLinkingFunction()` goes in reverse, **firing on the child first, then parent**, and so on.